# Firefox avoid cached response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, caching, browser

On Firefox 12, when I consecutively request two resources with the same URI but with different request headers (different accept fields), response is the cached response of the first request. First request is text/html request of the page which is correctly returned and the second request is like this:

Requested URL is: http://localhost:8080/test/ with these headers:

***Response Headers***

**Content-Type  text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1**
Date    Sun, 29 Apr 2012 19:41:53 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1

***Request Headers***

**Accept    application/json**
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=DB75F9F730D72D040CB5781903B60E87
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/test/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

Do you have any suggestions to avoid this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the sure way to fight browser cache is a random query string parameter.

Comment: @IliaG This should be an answer, not a comment. See also [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: none of the http response headers have any freshness info? like cache-control, last-modified, expires? Because I would think firefox wouldn't cache the response unless the server has declared it cacheable via http headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cache:false` in the `$.ajax({...})` params. This adds a random value to the querystring so it ensures no caching happens.

Comment: Caching should not be disabled, but still be done by the browser. The caching should be aware of the different mime types.

Comment: @koppor: I think that depends on the `Vary` header.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is sending different content based on different Accept headers, it should be sending "Vary: Accept" to tell caches that the Accept header needs to be part of the cache key.  Is your server doing that?

Comment: The line for Jerey is: `return Response.ok().header(HttpHeaders.VARY, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT).entity(viewable).build();`

Answer (score 0):

use the following line to apply cache false to all ajax request made using jquery

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

more options of [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Comment: This would disable caching. I assume the responses should be cached. The header field "Vary: Accept" seems to be the right place. See also http://www.subbu.org/blog/2007/12/vary-header-for-restful-applications.